# django import problem

Tags: django

When I try to import something inside application:

```
from app_name.models import something
```

i have import error,
I must do it:

```
from models import something
```

This problem occurs only in one of many apps in project. What should I change?

Comment: I guess that either your application is not on sys.path, or `__init__.py` is missing somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either what @Skirmantas suggested, that `app_name` is not on the `PYTHONPATH`, or you have a package clash, where some other `app_name` is preceding your `app_name` on the `PYTHONPATH`.

My hunch is that it's probably the latter, that you have an app that has the same package name as some other third-party app your using; I once had two top-level `registration` packages on my `PYTHONPATH`.

If you take my failure with the `registration` app as an example, you'll usually package your project something like this:

```
myproject/
    myproject/
         registration/
             __init__.py
             models.py
         __init__.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
    setup.py
```

It's a [community guideline](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models) that apps should be packaged to be "plug-and-play" compatible. They should be a top-level package and should be able to refer to intra-package resources through an absolute path like @Yuji suggested. If you like to ship and package your apps with your project, that means that in addition to `/myproject`, `/myproject/myproject` is also be on the `PYTHONPATH`. It's even [enforced in some cases](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py#L418).

As I said, it's just a hunch that you have clashing package names. If that's the case, then after this long-winded post you should understand that the only option you have is to rename your package to something more unique, but I would never have the heart to just spill it out immediately to someone. It's due to the sad truth that I've never found a more suitable name to replace `registration`.

Comment: Problem resolved. I had in my app file with the same name as app. So python was trying to import i.e. forms from this file, but not from app.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Sorry, but why would you want to change it? 
This way it's more DRY - you're not repeating the app_name over and over again - if you want to rename it in the future - it's gonna be easier.</strike>

EDIT: my question is answered below, I obviously didn't know about the fact that you should always import using full path.

As to direct answer, I have 2 guesses (not enough info to fully answer):

1. Maybe the app doesn't see itself as a module when you import from inside
2. You're missing some other import, generally to your app.

Sorry I couldn't be more precise.

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged.
      Always use the absolute package path for all imports.
      Even now that PEP 328 [7] is fully implemented in Python 2.5,
      its style of explicit relative imports is actively discouraged;
      absolute imports are more portable and usually more readable.