# Python Scripts and Classes outside Django App

Tags: python, django, django-views

Apologies if this is a duplicate question. I tried searching up my question but didn't find anything.

I have a Django Project with 3 Django Apps and the project directory looks like this

```
Project
|__ App_1
|__ App_2
|__ App_3
    |__ views.py
    |__ models.py
|__ scripts
    |__ class1.py
```

The `scripts` folder has python scripts that run algorithms using data from the database. I am using the Django Queryset to retrieve data. The `class1.py` file would look something like this:

```
from App_1.models import table1
.
.
.
```

When doing that, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'App_1'
```

Curious, I moved `class1.py` to the `App_1` folder and I got this error.

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I am a bit confused as to why BOTH methods did not work. What would be the best way to go about this? Ideally, I want to setup my scripts so I can just declare an object in a view-based function in `App_1/views.py`

Comment: Did you try `from Project.App_1.models import table1` or `from ..App_1.models import table1`

Comment: @OgulcanOlguner I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Project'` for the former and `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` for the latter. I am so confused because that should work? Should I add the `scripts` directory in the base DIR variable  or something?

Comment: There is a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088549/django-import-problem

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. If you see my directory, all the names are unique

Comment: Are you expecting these scripts to run by itself? So you're executing them as python scripts/foo.py? Cause, yes, that won't work. *"Ideally, I want to setup my scripts so I can just declare an object in a view-based function in App_1/views.py"* - that makes little sense. Perhaps you should study up on what a request/response cycle is and how a view fits in there.